# Alternative implementation of isType()

Tags: javascript

## Detecting types in JavaScript sucks

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array) discusses the standard way to check the type of a JavaScript object (specifically, an array):

> The method given in the ECMAScript standard to find the class of
>   Object is to use the toString method from Object.prototype.
>
> ```
> if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
>     alert( 'Array!' ); }
> ```

Why abuse `Object.prototype.toString`? It turns out that objects created in different frames have [different constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347298/use-of-tostring-instead-of-constructor-in-javascript/4347377#4347377).

`typeof` only works for objects which are (or have equivalent) primitives, like strings.

### Another way?

The above code makes me feel funny inside, and doesn’t have a chance of working for custom types, so I wrote this [[Gist](https://gist.github.com/1274551)]:

```
function isType(object, type){
     return object != null && type ? object.constructor.name === type.name : object === type;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
isType([1, 2, 3], Array);
isType(null, null);
isType('foo', String);
```

`mauke` on ##javascript points out that it fails for objects whose constructors have the same name as the type you're testing against:

```
isType(new (function String(){}), String);
```

I *think* I like this behavior more than calling every custom type an Object.

### To take it one step further

jQuery has a 25-line `isPlainObject` to tell if something is a plain object (`{ foo: 'bar' }`).

In what cases does the jQuery version behave more-correctly than…

```
isType(thing, Object);
```

?

<sup>Disclaimer: I haven’t tested this code in a bunch of cases or in a bunch of browsers. The experience concentrated into the jQuery source could blow me back to preschool.</sup>

Comment: One thing to consider: checking to see whether the constructor names are exactly equal (that is, the exact same string) may not work if it's possible for objects to "drift" between frames. That's one of the reasons that the big libraries don't do things like that -- each `window` has its own separate "Array" constructor, for example, and it's entirely possible that the name "Array" is distinct window by window also.

Comment: I thought `constructor` property wasn't reliable in a multi `window` environment too.

Comment: `isType(false, Boolean)`

Comment: @Pointy: Excellent point. In my testing, comparing the names does work across frames (unlike comparing the constructors themselves). Have you had a different experience?

Comment: @JohnFlatness: Thanks! Does this edit fix it?

Comment: No I haven't tried it but I have had problems with `x instanceof Array` for example

Comment: @Pointy: Exactly, and that problem is laid out in the second link. Otherwise, it would be great to compare `.constructor` directly or use `instanceof` (if it was OK to go up the prototype chain). I think that comparing the names of the constructors is an OK workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find anything wrong with your code,
so per Meta I am going to tell you why it is awesome ;)

- Checking `.toString()` is icky, `toString()` could easily be replaced/enhanced
- Your solution works across frames
- I was not able to break it.

On a final note, it seems to me that needing to verify the type of an object ( besides assertions ) means you are doing something odd and probably the code should be re-thought.

Still, I am favouriting this question.

UPDATE : Turns out that according to jsperf, your solution is much slower :\

Answer (score 2):

Alright I'm going to focus on some potential errors with your `isType` function.

The first obvious issue is you're relying on `constructor.name` being set. This isn't always the case - for instance consider any class declared `var MyClass = function() {}`. Now if you run `(new MyClass).constructor.name === ""`. Furthermore, many frameworks provide some class extension/constructs such as `Mootools` which would invalidate that check. Further issues may present themselves with code minification.

Out of curiosity, I decided to plug your code into the [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org) test suite to see how it would do. I couldn't implement `_.isObject`  as it accepts multiple types as objects. [It passes all the tests but the ones for `NaN` understandably](http://jsbin.com/regereyu/4). I excluded the `iframe` tests as I couldn't get them working on gists or jsbin but they pass as well. Not bad :)!

[image]

**Edit** this will also not work for objects created via `Object.create` unfortunately.

`isType(Object.create(null), Object)` will throw a `TypeError` as the resulting object will have no `constructor` property

Similarly it will fail for any Object that has a `constructor` property... consider

```
var obj = {
   constructor: "foo"
};
```

**Edit 2** It appears this also incorrectly? suggests the `arguments` object is a Object.

```
(function() {
   isType(arguments, Object) === true;
})([1])
```