# Type / Constructor testing utilities

Tags: javascript, node.js

My [argument sanitization](https://www.github.com/silvinci/node-sanitize-arguments) lib has a byproduct which does some typechecking and constructor investigation. I'm unsure if I'm using the fastest / most efficient approach here.

What are your opinions? Total rubbish or does it have a right to exist? ;)

```
// Return the type of an object aka safe typeof
function typeOf(o) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(o).match(/(\w+)\]/)[1];
}

// Return the name of a function aka class name
function nameOf(o) {
    return typeOf(o) == "Function"
        ? Function.prototype.toString.call(o).match(/function\s?(\w*)\(/)[1]
        : false;
}

// Return the expected arguments of a function
function argumentsOf(o) {
    if(typeOf(o) == "Function") {
        var args = Function.prototype.toString.call(o).match(/\((.+)\)\s*{/);
        if(!!args && !!args[1]) return args[1].replace(/\s+/g, "").split(",");
        else return [];
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: You could return the string `"anonymous"` instead of `false` for a function name. Also it will throw an error for `[1]` because `.match()` can return `null`

Comment: I prefer `false`. Are there any substantial benefits?

Comment: Function should always match the pattern and `[1]` should therefore always match. But just to be safe, I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: `false` is not a string, though returning an empty string is viable as well. Getting a boolean from a function named `nameOf` is kinda iffy :P

Comment: I think we got something twisted here: `false`is returned when no function was given and `nameOf` doesn't know what to do. `""` is returned when there is no function name. I think it's safer than `"anonymous"`, because some weird users might name their function `anonymous` and then things would blow up.

Comment: I thought about throwing a `TypeError` (which is generally safer) instead of returning `false`, but then simple loose-type control statements would have to involve `try { ... } catch { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

Fun question,

I believe the only reliable way of getting the name and parameters of a function is to indeed parse the `toString`. However, you can figure out whether the parameter is a function without a regex. I would propose from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5278/14625) :

```
function isType(object, type){
     return object != null && type ? object.constructor.name === type.name : object === type;
}

// Return the name of a function aka class name
function nameOf(o) {
    return isType( o , Function )
        ? Function.prototype.toString.call(o).match(/function\s?(\w*)\(/)[1]
        : false;
}
```

There are still a few things that bother me here, why is the parameter name `o`, which is the Spartan convention for `Object` whereas we expect a `f`unction ? Also, why name the function `nameOf`, which creates an expectation of being to name anything whereas it really only can give the name for a function, maybe it ought to be called `nameOfFunction` or `functionName()`. Finally, as per the comments, making a function with `name` return `false` is making the name lie, just return ''. Something like this then:

```
// Return the name of a function aka class name
function functionName(f) {
    return isType( f , Function )
        ? Function.prototype.toString.call(f).match(/function\s?(\w*)\(/)[1]
        : '';
}
```

Finally, for `argumentsOf`, I sincerely dislike dropping the newline in `if` statements, removing curly braces is fine, but no newlines makes it too hard to read.